# Failed to load resource 403 Forbidden - static bootstrap/html site on Herkou - permission issue

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, heroku, composer-php

Currently learning HTML5/CSS3/Bootstrap and I found online that I can deploy my static sites to Heroku by spoofing it as a php site.

My site is able to load when deployed to Heroku but isn't loading the Boostrap/css files. I'm seeing a bunch of 403's particularly stemming from a folder I have called vendor which includes all my boostrap files. I think Heroku doesn't have sufficient permissions to access the folder.

List of errors from Chrome Dev Tools Console

[image]

After a bunch of browsing I read that I can include the composer.json file filled out with some chmod commands to resolve the issue.

My composer.json looks like the following:

```
{
 "scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "chmod -R 777 vendor"
    ]
 }
}
```

My folder structure (not the best) that I'm deploying to heroku looks like the following:

Folder Structure

[image]

I would really appreciate any help how to get this working as I plan to work on other boostrap projects and use heroku to deploy. I think it's a permissions issue that can be solved with the correct contents in the composer.json

Comment: I haven't worked with heroku, but do you FTP/SFTP or have shell access? If you use FTP/SFTP, you should be able to change the permissions of the remote files. Or with a shell, you can just execute the `chmod` commands  against the files in the shell. You probably don't want 777... that gives anyone write access to the files. 755 is probably what you're going for. That gives the file owner 7 (read, write, execute), and the group and other users 5 (read, execute)

Comment: Thanks @MichaelCoker. 777 vs 775 is clear now. I will read more into it. I believe I don't have FTP/SFTP access to the files on Heroku but the way to solve this problem would be to configure the composer.json file appropriately and include the permission in there. If folks have advice how to do that, it would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of vendor folder. I guess vendor(bin also) name is reserved in Heroku platform. So just try to change vendor folder name to something else.